API tests are all passing, but still giving a time-out error
I am trying to unit test all of my API calls. Every call passes the test, but i still get an error saying: ✘ Timed out while running tests Failed to exit when running test.js. I have tried adding a timeout of 20sec, but this didnt do anything.
test.js:
const test = require('ava');
const request = require('supertest');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

// Mock database operations
const dbMock = {
  getBikes: sinon.stub().callsFake((callback) => callback(null, [{ id: 1, name: 'Bike 1' }])),
  getUsers: sinon.stub().callsFake((callback) => callback(null, [{ id: 1, name: 'User 1' }])),
  getBikeUsage: sinon.stub().callsFake((callback) => callback(null, [{ id: 1, bikeId: 1, userId: 1 }])),
  saveBikeUsage: sinon.stub().callsFake((bikeUsage, callback) => callback(null, { insertId: 1 })),
  updateBikeUsageStatus: sinon.stub().callsFake((bikeId, status, callback) => callback(null, {})),
  unassignBike: sinon.stub().callsFake((bikeId, endTime, callback) => callback(null, {})),
  updateBikeDetails: sinon.stub().callsFake((id, details, callback) => callback(null, {})),
  updateUserDetails: sinon.stub().callsFake((id, name, callback) => callback(null, {})),
  addUser: sinon.stub().callsFake((name, callback) => callback(null, { insertId: 1 })),
  addBike: sinon.stub().callsFake((bike, callback) => callback(null, { insertId: 1 })),
  getUserById: sinon.stub().callsFake((userId, callback) => callback(null, [{ id: userId, name: 'User 1' }])),
  getUserHistory: sinon.stub().callsFake((userId, callback) => callback(null, [{ id: 1, bikeId: 1, userId: userId }])),
  addCommentToBike: sinon.stub().callsFake((bikeId, comment, callback) => callback(null, {})),
};

// Proxyquire to replace './db' with our mock
const app = proxyquire('./server', { './db': dbMock });

test.afterEach.always(() => {
  sinon.restore(); // Restore all stubs and spies after each test
});

// Test for GET /bikes endpoint
test('GET /bikes returns list of bikes', async (t) => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/bikes');
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.true(Array.isArray(res.body));
  t.true(res.body.length > 0);
});

// Test for GET /users endpoint
test('GET /users returns list of users', async (t) => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/users');
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.true(Array.isArray(res.body));
  t.true(res.body.length > 0);
});

// Test for GET /bike-usage endpoint
test('GET /bike-usage returns list of bike usage history', async (t) => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/bike-usage');
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.true(Array.isArray(res.body));
  t.true(res.body.length > 0);
});

// Test for POST /bike-usage endpoint
test('POST /bike-usage saves bike usage data', async (t) => {
  const bikeUsage = { bike_id: 1, user_id: 1, start_time: new Date().toISOString(), end_time: null };
  const res = await request(app).post('/bike-usage').send(bikeUsage);
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.message, 'Bike usage data saved successfully');
});

// Test for POST /bike-unassign endpoint
test('POST /bike-unassign unassigns bike and updates end time', async (t) => {
  const bike_id = 1;
  const res = await request(app).post('/bike-unassign').send({ bike_id });
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.message, 'Bike unassigned successfully');
});

// Test for PUT /bikes/:id endpoint
test('PUT /bikes/:id updates bike details', async (t) => {
  const bikeId = 1;
  const details = { frame: 'New Frame', bike_lock: 'New Lock', comments: 'Updated comment', broken: false };
  const res = await request(app).put(`/bikes/${bikeId}`).send(details);
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.message, 'Bike details updated successfully');
});

// Test for PUT /users/:id endpoint
test('PUT /users/:id updates user details', async (t) => {
  const userId = 1;
  const name = 'Updated User';
  const res = await request(app).put(`/users/${userId}`).send({ name });
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.message, 'User details updated successfully');
});

// Test for POST /users endpoint
test('POST /users adds new user', async (t) => {
  const name = 'New User';
  const res = await request(app).post('/users').send({ name });
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.name, name);
  t.true(res.body.id > 0);
});

// Test for POST /bikes endpoint
test('POST /bikes adds new bike', async (t) => {
  const bike = { frame: 'New Frame', bike_lock: 'New Lock', broken: false, comments: 'New comment' };
  const res = await request(app).post('/bikes').send(bike);
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.true(res.body.id > 0);
  t.deepEqual(res.body.frame, bike.frame);
});

// Test for GET /users/:id endpoint
test('GET /users/:id returns user details for valid ID', async (t) => {
  const userId = 1;
  const res = await request(app).get(`/users/${userId}`);
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.deepEqual(parseInt(res.body.id), userId);
});

// Test for GET /user-history/:userId endpoint
test('GET /user-history/:userId returns user history for valid user ID', async (t) => {
  const userId = 1;
  const res = await request(app).get(`/user-history/${userId}`);
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.true(Array.isArray(res.body));
  t.true(res.body.length > 0);
});

// Test for POST /bikes/:bikeId/comments endpoint
test('POST /bikes/:bikeId/comments adds comment to bike', async (t) => {
  const bikeId = 1;
  const comment = 'New Comment';
  const res = await request(app).post(`/bikes/${bikeId}/comments`).send({ comment });
  t.is(res.status, 200);
  t.is(res.body.message, 'Comment saved successfully');
});


db.js:
const mysql = require('mysql2');

// Create a connection pool
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'xxxx',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx',
  database: 'xxxx',
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
});

module.exports = {
  getBikes: (callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Bikes', callback);
  },
  getUsers: (callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Users', callback);
  },
  getBikeUsage: (callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM BikeUsage', callback);
  },
  saveBikeUsage: (bikeUsage, callback) => {
    const { bike_id, user_id, start_time, end_time } = bikeUsage;
    const formattedStartTime = start_time.slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
    pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO BikeUsage (bike_id, user_id, start_time, end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [bike_id, user_id, formattedStartTime, end_time],
      callback
    );
  },
  updateBikeUsageStatus: (bike_id, isBeingUsed, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE Bikes SET isBeingUsed = ? WHERE id = ?',
      [isBeingUsed, bike_id],
      callback
    );
  },
  unassignBike: (bike_id, endTime, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE BikeUsage SET end_time = ? WHERE bike_id = ? AND end_time IS NULL',
      [endTime, bike_id],
      callback
    );
  },
  updateBikeDetails: (id, details, callback) => {
    const { frame, bike_lock, comments, broken } = details;
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE Bikes SET frame = ?, bike_lock = ?, comments = ?, broken = ? WHERE id = ?',
      [frame, bike_lock, comments, broken, id],
      callback
    );
  },
  updateUserDetails: (id, name, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE Users SET name = ? WHERE id = ?',
      [name, id],
      callback
    );
  },
  addUser: (name, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO Users (name) VALUES (?)',
      [name],
      callback
    );
  },
  addBike: (bike, callback) => {
    const { frame, bike_lock, broken, comments } = bike;
    pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO Bikes (frame, bike_lock, broken, comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [frame, bike_lock, broken, comments],
      callback
    );
  },
  getUserById: (userId, callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = ?', [userId], callback);
  },
  getUserHistory: (userId, callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM BikeUsage WHERE user_id = ?', [userId], callback);
  },
  addCommentToBike: (bikeId, comment, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE Bikes SET comments = CONCAT(IFNULL(comments, ""), ?) WHERE id = ?',
      [comment + '\n', bikeId],
      callback
    );
  }
};


Test results:

flinkregi_backend@1.0.0 test
ava

Server running on port 3000
  ✔ GET /bikes returns list of bikes (146ms)
  ✔ GET /users returns list of users (145ms)
  ✔ GET /bike-usage returns list of bike usage history (144ms)
  ✔ POST /bike-usage saves bike usage data (143ms)
  ✔ POST /bike-unassign unassigns bike and updates end time (142ms)
  ✔ PUT /bikes/:id updates bike details (139ms)
  ✔ PUT /users/:id updates user details (137ms)
  ✔ POST /users adds new user (138ms)
  ✔ POST /bikes adds new bike (137ms)
  ✔ GET /users/:id returns user details for valid ID (136ms)
  ✔ GET /user-history/:userId returns user history for valid user ID (136ms)
  ✔ POST /bikes/:bikeId/comments adds comment to bike (137ms)
  
  ✘ Timed out while running tests

  Failed to exit when running test.js

  ─

  12 tests passed

I tried adding: test.afterEach.always(() => {sinon.restore(); // Restore all stubs and spies after each test});
Also tried adding a timeout:
test.beforeEach(async (t) => { t.timeout(10000); // 10 seconds timeout });

Have you tried calling pool.end(cb) after all your tests completes?

Something is keeping the test worker alive after AVA has completed the test run. Quite possibly your DB pool is actually connected and needs to be closed. You'd have to do the same in a production environment to ensure a clean shutdown.
